# $H_2(G,\mathbb{Q})$ for finitely presented group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

I am learning about group homology and spectral sequences and I have read somewhere that we can use the Lyndon-Serre-Hochschild spectral sequence to prove that $H_2(G,\mathbb{Q})$ has finite rank when $G$ is finitely presented but I cannot write it down.

I have tried applying the LSH spectral sequence to the exact sequence $1\to N\to F\to F/N\to 1$ with $F$ free and $G\cong F/N$ but I don't reach any conclussions.

Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Comment: What are you reading? My suggestion is to read Brown's "Cohomology of groups". From there, you will learn that finite presentability implies $FP_2$ and the latter implies finite rank of $H^2$.

Comment: I read the statement on a file I found online. It said that it follows "easily" using the LSH spectral sequence so I tried to do it as an exercise but I couldn't find the proof. Do you know a proof using spectral sequences? I have learnt about the LHS spectral sequence using Brown's book

Comment: No, I do not. And I would not necessarily trust a random statement found online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several misfires, I have it now.

Let $G$ be a finitely presented group; there is a free group $F$ on $n\in\Bbb N$ letters and a subset $R$ of $m$ words of $F$, and a specified isomorphism $G\cong F/\overline{\langle R\rangle}$ where the bar denotes normal closure and the braces denote subgroup generation.

The Lydon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence applied to the trivial $F$-module $\Bbb Q$ and the pair $(G,\overline{\langle R\rangle})$ is convergent to $H_\ast(F;\Bbb Q)$ (under some mysterious filtration) and has $E^2$ page: $$E^2_{p,q}\cong H_p(G;H_q(\overline{\langle R\rangle};\Bbb Q))\implies H_{p+q}(F;\Bbb Q)$$

Here, $H_q(\overline{\langle R\rangle};\Bbb Q)$ is abstractly - but canonically - a $F/\overline{\langle R\rangle}\cong G$-module. It will be very important to understand specifically what the $G$-action is. I investigated the generalities of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4838696) (thanks again to Mariano). Even though $\Bbb Q$ is a trivial module, this homology module is **not** necessarily a trivial $G$-module.

There is the $5$-term exact sequence in low degree associated to the spectral sequence: $$H_2(F;\Bbb Q)\to H_2(G;H_0(\overline{\langle R\rangle};\Bbb Q))\to H_0(G;H_1(\overline{\langle R\rangle};\Bbb Q))\to H_1(F;\Bbb Q)\\\to H_1(G;H_0(\overline{\langle R\rangle};\Bbb Q))\to0$$

We need to understand these terms. Firstly (see Weibel's "Homological Algebra" chapter $6$ as a reference for my claims) $H_2(F;\Bbb Q)=0$ since $F$ is a free group. $H_1(F;\Bbb Q)\cong F^{\mathsf{ab}}\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q\cong\Bbb Q^n$ where the first isomorphism comes from the fact $\Bbb Q$ is here considered a trivial $F$-module and the second isomorphism from the fact $F^{\mathsf{ab}}\cong\Bbb Z^n$. Similarly, by triviality of $\Bbb Q$ as an $\overline{\langle R\rangle}$-module, the $H_0$ terms are just isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ and the $H_1$ term is isomorphic to $\overline{\langle R\rangle}^{\mathsf{ab}}\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q$.

So the sequence is: $$0\to H_2(G;\Bbb Q)\to H_0(G;\overline{\langle R\rangle}^{\mathsf{ab}}\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q)\to\Bbb Q^n\to H_1(G;\Bbb Q)\to0$$However, for the sake of rigour it is our duty to figure out how "$\Bbb Q$" has inherited a $G$-module structure in the first and final nonzero terms. We *need* it to be the trivial structure, but a priori $H_0(\overline{\langle R\rangle};\Bbb Q)$ inherits a mysterious $G$-action.

The isomorphism $H_0(\overline{\langle R\rangle};\Bbb Q)\cong\Bbb Q$ is induced from - if you compute $H_0$ via a bar resolution - $\Bbb Z[\overline{\langle R\rangle}]\otimes_{\Bbb Z[\overline{\langle R\rangle}]}\Bbb Q\cong\Bbb Z[\overline{\langle R\rangle}]\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q$, the map induced by $(\sum_i r_in_i)\otimes q\mapsto \sum_i n_iq$. In particular, $q\in\Bbb Q$ is identifiable with $1\otimes q\in\Bbb Z[\overline{\langle R\rangle}]\otimes_{\Bbb Z[\overline{\langle R\rangle}]}\Bbb Q$. The $G$-action on the bar resolution (see my linked post, but dualise since we use a right bar resolution now) would map $q$ to $gq$ in the $g(1)g^{-1}$th summand i.e. map $1\otimes q$ to $1\otimes q\sim q$. Thus, the inherited $G$-action on $H_0(\overline{\langle R\rangle};\Bbb Q)\cong\Bbb Q$ is the trivial one and we are justified in writing "$H_2(G;\Bbb Q),H_1(G;\Bbb Q)$" in the exact sequence.

However, the action on $H_1(\overline{\langle R\rangle};\Bbb Q)$ usually is *not* trivial. Let $\pi:\overline{\langle R\rangle}\to\overline{\langle R\rangle}^{\mathsf{ab}}$ denote the Abelianisation map. It can be shown that $H_1(\overline{\langle R\rangle};\Bbb Q)\cong\overline{\langle R\rangle}^{\mathsf{ab}}\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q$ is induced from the following map on the bar resolution: $B_1\otimes_{\Bbb Z[\overline{\langle R\rangle}]}\Bbb Q\to\overline{\langle R\rangle}^{\mathsf{ab}}\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q$, $\left(\sum_i[r'_i]r_in_i\right)\otimes q\mapsto\left(\sum_in_i\pi(r'_i)\right)\otimes q$.

Let $x=\pi(r)\in\overline{\langle R\rangle}^{\mathsf{ab}}$. $x\otimes q$ is represented by $[r]\otimes q$ in the bar model. The $G$-action by some $g$ is, according to my post, going to be $g(x\otimes q):=[grg^{-1}]\otimes gq=[grg^{-1}]\otimes q$. Now here's the thing; every element of $\overline{\langle R\rangle}$ is obtainable, by conjugating finitely many times, from an element of $\langle R\rangle$. Zeroth homology takes coinvariants and identifies $\pi(grg^{-1})\otimes q\sim[grg^{-1}]\otimes q\sim x\otimes q$. It follows all zeroth homology classes will be representable by an element of $\pi(\langle R\rangle)\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q$.

However, $\pi(\langle R\rangle)\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q$ is an Abelian group generated by at most $m$ elements tensored with $\Bbb Q$ and thus is a $\Bbb Q$-vector space of dimension $d\le m$. When we take zeroth homology, we are going to take a quotient of this and this again results in a $\Bbb Q$-vector space of dimension $\le m$. Therefore the exact sequence is: $$0\to H_2(G;\Bbb Q)\to\Bbb Q^k\to\Bbb Q^n\to H_1(G;\Bbb Q)\to0$$Where $0\le k\le m$.

It follows that $H_2(G;\Bbb Q)$ is a $\Bbb Q$-vector space of dimension $d\le m$ and that $H_1(G;\Bbb Q)$ is a $\Bbb Q$-vector space of dimension $n-m\le d\le n$. This shows these groups are of finite rank and gives you an estimate on the size of this rank.

Comment: Vanishing of $H_2(G, {\mathbb Q})$ is an utterly wrong claim, just work out the example of $G={\mathbb Z}^2$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I now realise my mistake.

Comment: Also, "a finitely generated normal subgroup of $F$" is also wrong. I suggest you delete the current answer since it is rather misleading.

Comment: Looks right. Still, using the LSH spectral sequence is a way too hard a proof, comparing the more natural approach of forming projective resolutions via presentation complexes.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I agree this is probably overkill. I have never heard of presentation complexes actually, I'm new to the subject and Weibel doesn't cover them. Where can I learn about them and how to use them in calculations? Thanks for the feedback

Comment: It should be in Brown's book. You have probably learned presentation complexes in your algebraic topology class, just maybe not under that name: Given a group presentation, take the wedge of circles, one for each generator. Then each defining relator will give you a loop in the wedge of circles. Attach 2-cells along such loops. The result is a presentation complex. Another good place to read about this is in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology".

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah I'm familiar with that construction, but it sounds like you're suggesting there's a homological interpretation of it. Then presumably there's a $3$ dimensional, $n$-dimensional variant of it for computing higher homology

Comment: Right. You build a resolution by taking the universal cover and the corresponding cellular chain complex (the group acts naturally by permuting cells). This is the beginning of "topological methods" in homological algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea: Since $G$ is finitely presented, we can write $G \cong \langle F\rangle / \langle R \rangle$ with $|F|,|R| < \infty$. You probably want to use the five-term exact sequence which is a direct consequence of the LSH spectral sequence, see Corollary 6.4 on page 171 in Brown's book. Using the fact that $H_1(G;M) \cong G^{\text{ab}} \otimes M$ for $M$ an abelian group with trivial $G$-action, the first three terms of the five-term exact sequence applied to $1 \to \langle R\rangle \to \langle F\rangle \to G \to 1$ yield an exact sequence
$$
H_2(F;\mathbb{Q}) \to H_2(G;\mathbb{Q}) \to \langle R\rangle^{\text{ab}} \otimes \mathbb{Q}.
$$
Notice that $R^{\text{ab}} \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is torsion-free and has finite rank (since $R$ was finite). Your claim should now follow, since $H_2(F;\mathbb{Q}) \cong 0$, i.e. the second map is injective.

Feel free to point out any mistakes here; I did not think everything through rigorously.

Comment: What is $R^{ab}$? If you mean abelianization of the subgroup generated by $R$ then it has infinite rank.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't see how $\langle R\rangle^{\text{ab}}$ has infinite rank. I mean, if $|R|=n$, then $\langle R\rangle^{\text{ab}} \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the normal closure of $R$. Without taking the normal closure you will not get an exact sequence.

Comment: Also, the line "$G \cong \langle F\rangle /   R \rangle$" is **not even wrong.** The correct statement is that "$G \cong F /   \langle R^F\rangle$", where $\langle R^F\rangle$ denotes the normal closure of $R$ in the free group $F$.

Comment: You are using wrong definition of finite presentability. Free groups $F$ contain very few finitely generated normal subgroups: Every such subgroup is either trivial or has finite index in $F$ .

Comment: @MoisheKohan We know $\langle R^F\rangle^{\mathsf{ab}}\otimes\Bbb Q/H_2(G;\Bbb Q)\subset\Bbb Q^{|F|}$ so this should imply $H_2(G;\Bbb Q)$ is a finite index subspace of $\langle R^F\rangle\otimes\Bbb Q$ and you seem to claim the latter is infinite dimensional most of the time, so surely this implies $H_2(G;\Bbb Q)$ is, most of the time, infinite dimensional?

Comment: @FShrike: This is not what I wrote.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't see how. $\langle R^F\rangle^{\mathsf{ab}}$ has infinite rank iff. $\langle R^F\rangle^{\mathsf{ab}}\otimes\Bbb Q$ is an infinite dimensional $\Bbb Q$-vector space

Comment: @FShrike: From what I wrote, indeed $\langle R^F\rangle^{ab}\otimes Q$ is infinite-dimensional (with few exceptions). However, I never claimed that $⟨^⟩^{}\otimes Q/_2(;ℚ)$ embeds in $Q^{||}$. This is wrong and I do not know where did it come from.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Doesn't it follow from the $5$-term exact sequence jasnee refers to? $0\to H_2(G;\Bbb Q)\to (R^F)^{\mathsf{ab}}\otimes\Bbb Q\to H_1(F;\Bbb Q)\cong\Bbb Q^{|F|}\to H_1(G;\Bbb Q)\to0$

Comment: @FShrike: It is a garbled version of what is written by Brown. Take a look in Brown's book.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Well, $H_1(F;\Bbb Q)$ fits into an exact sequence with $F_0H_1=E^\infty_{0,1}$ and $F_1/F_0=E^{\infty}_{1,0}$ and these are exactly $E^2_{0,1}/d^2(E^2_{2,0})$ and $E^2_{1,0}$ i.e. $((R^F)^{ab}\otimes Q)/H_2(G;Q)$ and $H_1(G;Q)$ respectively. I see no mistake. and $d^2$ injects in this case

Comment: @FShrike: Now compare what you wrote to what Brown wrote in Corollary 6.4.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Respectfully, could you please specify what exactly I said which is in error? The $5$ term exact sequence I wrote out is a copy of the one presented by Weibel (whose book I have on hand), noting that $H_1(\overline{R};\Bbb Q)$ is a trivial $G$ module isomorphic to $\overline{R}^{\mathsf{ab}}\otimes_\Bbb Z\Bbb Q\cong\Bbb Q^{|\overline{R}|}$ and that $H_1(F;\Bbb Q)\cong\Bbb Q^{|F|}$, $H_2(F;\Bbb Q)\cong0$

Comment: @FShrike The mistake is in the claim that the module is trivial. But maybe you should ask a separate question since comments are really not meant for such conversations.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks. Now that you’ve pointed it out, I realise the error. Just because $\Bbb Q$ is trivial doesn’t mean some free resolution of it will be a resolution by trivial modules. To Janess, this is our mistake. The relevant term of the $E^2$ page is $H_0(G;H_1(\overline{R};\Bbb Q))$ which is **not** necessarily isomorphic to $H_1(\overline{R};\Bbb Q)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Seems like I did miss that! Should I delete my answer in your opinion then?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I believe I now have a correct answer, taking into account the non-triviality of the module structure on $H_1(\overline{\langle R\rangle};\Bbb Q)$. Would you mind taking a look? Also to Jasnee, if you're interested