The definition of action of $G/H$ on group cohomology $H^1(H,M)$
Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.
Let $M$ be $G$-module. Let $H^1(H,M)$ be first group cohomology.
$G$ acts on $H^1(H,M)$ by $(\sigma*f)(g):=gf({\sigma}^{-1}g{\sigma})$・・・①.

My question is, how $G/H$ acts on $H^1(H,M)$ ?

My thought : Let $\sigma  \mathrm{mod}H\in G/H$. Action ① is trivial for $H$ modulo coboundary.In other words, if $\sigma_1≡\sigma_2 \text{mod} H, (\sigma_1 \text{mod}H)*X) (f)(g)-(\sigma_2 \text{mod}H)*X) (f)(g) \in B^1(H,M)$.
(See Ehud Meir's comment in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212636/the-term-h1n-ag-n-in-the-inflation-restriction-exact-sequence), so we can define $(\sigma \text{mod}H *f)(g):=\sigma f({\sigma}^{-1}g{\sigma})$.
But I often see $\sigma \in G/H$ acts on $H^1(H,M)$ by just $(\sigma*f)(g):=gf({\sigma}^{-1}g{\sigma})$(For example, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461065/tate-shafarevich-group-and-sigma-phic-phi-sigmac-for-all-c-in-oper).Is it correct to understand that the explanation here is omitted, and it is simply written as if $\sigma$ is acting directly?

I think you're missing some annotation on the cohomology group. Nothing you wrote about $H^1$ or the action even mentioned $H$, so it's unlikely it acts trivially (wouldn't that mean all normal subgroups act trivially)?

@Steve Thank you for your reaction. I modified my question.

I discuss stuff about this in detail here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4838696/815585. Not even about the definition, but actually computing it based on the definition. There is a more fundamental abstract and formal definition which is important for, say, the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence to work, and then it is a theorem that the action is $gf(\sigma^{-1}g\sigma)$

@FShirike Is your $\sigma$ in $G/H$ (not $G - H$)? And is it well-defined as described in my question?

I was reminded of you. I appreciated your very detailed responses. I would be happy to learn more from you in the future.
